# Linker Error outside of global text segment

Tags: c++, linker

We see below linker error with gcc, what does this error indicate. Does it have anything to do with the linker definition file ?

```
ERROR: found static function _ZNSt8_Rb_treeIjSt4pairIKjP11BFD_SESSIONESt10_Select1stIS4_ESt4lessIjESaIS4_EE14_M_lower_boundEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS4_ESD_RS1_$isra$84 outside of the global text segment
ERROR: (perhaps you marked a static function as hot?)
```

Linker script is below-->

```
/* Script for ld -r: link without relocation */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64",
          "elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)
  /* For some reason, the Solaris linker makes bad executables
   if gld -r is used and the intermediate file has sections starting
   at non-zero addresses.  Could be a Solaris ld bug, could be a GNU ld
   bug.  But for now assigning the zero vmas works.  */
 SECTIONS
 {
   /* Read-only sections, merged into text segment: */
   .interp       0 : { *(.interp) }
   .note.gnu.build-id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
   .hash         0 : { *(.hash) }
   .gnu.hash     0 : { *(.gnu.hash) }
   .dynsym       0 : { *(.dynsym) }
   .dynstr       0 : { *(.dynstr) }
   .gnu.version  0 : { *(.gnu.version) }
   .gnu.version_d 0: { *(.gnu.version_d) }
   .gnu.version_r 0: { *(.gnu.version_r) }
   .rela.init    0 : { *(.rela.init) }
   .rela.text    0 : { *(.rela.text) }
   .rela.fini    0 : { *(.rela.fini) }
   .rela.rodata  0 : { *(.rela.rodata) }
   .rela.data.rel.ro 0 : { *(.rela.data.rel.ro) }
   .rela.data    0 : { *(.rela.data) }
   .rela.tdata  0 : { *(.rela.tdata) }
   .rela.tbss   0 : { *(.rela.tbss) }
   .rela.ctors   0 : { *(.rela.ctors) }
   .rela.dtors   0 : { *(.rela.dtors) }
   .rela.got     0 : { *(.rela.got) }
   .rela.bss     0 : { *(.rela.bss) }
   .rela.ldata   0 : { *(.rela.ldata) }
   .rela.lbss    0 : { *(.rela.lbss) }
   .rela.lrodata 0 : { *(.rela.lrodata) }
   .rela.ifunc   0 : { *(.rela.ifunc) }
   .rela.plt     0 :
     {
       *(.rela.plt)
     }
   .init         0 :
   {
     KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
   }
   .plt          0 : { *(.plt) *(.iplt) }
   .hot          0 : { *(.text.hot) }
   .text         0 :
   {
     /* merge .text.* sections into the .text segment in the first pass link 
        so that all static functions are in the same segment and the relative
        offsets reported by nm/readelf can be used to determine the final
        absolute address of the function in the image. */
     *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
     /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf32.em.  */
     *(.gnu.warning)
   }
   .fini         0 :
   {
     KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
   }
.rodata       0 : { *(.rodata) }
   .rodata1      0 : { *(.rodata1) }
   .eh_frame_hdr : { *(.eh_frame_hdr) }
   .eh_frame     0 : ONLY_IF_RO { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) }
   .gcc_except_table 0 : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gcc_except_table
   .gcc_except_table.*) }
   /* These sections are generated by the Sun/Oracle C++ compiler.  */
   .exception_ranges 0 : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.exception_ranges
   .exception_ranges*) }
   /* Adjust the address for the data segment.  We want to adjust up to
      the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
   /* Exception handling  */
   .eh_frame     0 : ONLY_IF_RW { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) }
   .gcc_except_table 0 : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
   .exception_ranges 0 : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.exception_ranges .exception_ranges*) }
   /* Thread Local Storage sections  */
   .tdata   0 : { *(.tdata) }
   .tbss        0 : { *(.tbss) }
   .preinit_array   0 :
   {
     KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
   }
   .jcr          0 : { KEEP (*(.jcr)) }
   .dynamic      0 : { *(.dynamic) }
   .got          0 : { *(.got) *(.igot) }
   .got.plt      0 : { *(.got.plt)  *(.igot.plt) }
   .data         0 :
   {
     *(.data)
   }
   .data1        0 : { *(.data1) }
   .bss          0 :
   {
    *(.dynbss)
    *(.bss)
    *(COMMON)
    /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
       _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
       .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
       FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we don't
       pad the .data section.  */
   }
   .lbss 0 :
   {
     *(.dynlbss)
     *(.lbss)
     *(LARGE_COMMON)
   }
   .lrodata 0  :
   {
     *(.lrodata)
   }
   .ldata 0  :
   {
     *(.ldata)
   }
   /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
   .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
   .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
   .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
   .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
   .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
   .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
   .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
   /* DWARF debug sections.
      Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
      of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
   /* DWARF 1 */
   .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
   .line           0 : { *(.line) }
   /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
   .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
   .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
   /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
   .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
   .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
   /* DWARF 2 */
   .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info) }
   .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
   .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line) }
   .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
   .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
   .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
   .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
   /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
   .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
   .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
   .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
   .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
   /* DWARF 3 */
   .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
   .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
   /* DWARF Extension.  */
   .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }
   .gnu.attributes 0 : { KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes)) }
 }

From the linker script we find that .text.* i.e all section with any suffix after .text.* is placed under .text section. We find that certain functions are suffixed to .text.xxxx as unique section names.  We dont find the compiler option "-function-sections" in our compilation steps.
```

Snippet from the objdump----->
        objs/bfdproto/x86_64/bfdp_proto.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

```
    SYMBOL TABLE:
    0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 bfdp_proto.cpp
    0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
    0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
    0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
    0000000000000000 l    d  .text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIjSt4pairIKjP11BFD_SESSIONESt10_Select1stIS4_ESt4lessIjESaIS4_EE14_M_lower_boundEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS4_ESD_RS1_$isra$84    0000000000000000 .text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIjSt4pairIKjP11BFD_SESSIONESt10_Select1stIS4_ESt4lessIjESaIS4_EE14_M_lower_boundEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS4_ESD_RS1_$isra$84
    0000000000000000 l     F .text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIjSt4pairIKjP11BFD_SESSIONESt10_Select1stIS4_ESt4lessIjESaIS4_EE14_M_lower_boundEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS4_ESD_RS1_$isra$84    000000000000002c __ZNSt8_Rb_treeIjSt4pairIKjP11BFD_SESSIONESt10_Select1stIS4_ESt4lessIjESaIS4_EE14_M_lower_boundEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS4_ESD_RS1_$isra$84
    0000000000000000 l    d  .text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeI14BFD_RXINFO_KEYSt4pairIKS0_P11BFD_SESSIONESt10_Select1stIS5_ESt4lessIS0_ESaIS5_EE14_M_lower_boundEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS5_ESE_RS2_$isra$87 0000000000000000 .text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeI14BFD_RXINFO_KEYSt4pairIKS0_P11BFD_SESSIONESt10_Select1stIS5_ESt4lessIS0_ESaIS5_EE14_M_lower_boundEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS5_ESE_RS2_$isra$87
    0000000000000000 l     F .text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeI14BFD_RXINFO_KEYSt4pairIKS0_P11BFD_SESSIONESt10_Select1stIS5_ESt4lessIS0_ESaIS5_EE14_M_lower_boundEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS5_ESE_RS2_$isra$87 000000000000004a __ZNSt8_Rb_treeI14BFD_RXINFO_KEYSt4pairIKS0_P11BFD_SESSIONESt10_Select1stIS5_ESt4lessIS0_ESaIS5_EE14_M_lower_boundEPSt13_Rb_tree_nodeIS5_ESE_RS2_$isra$87
    0000000000000180 l     F .text  0000000000000029 __ZNSt4listIP11BFD_SESSIONSaIS1_EE5eraseESt14_List_iteratorIS1_E$isra$92
    00000000000001b0 l     F .text  000000000000006b __ZNSt4listIP11BFD_SESSIONSaIS1_EE6insertESt14_List_iteratorIS1_ERKS1_$isra$90
    0000000000000000 l    d  .rodata.str1.1 0000000000000000 .rodata.str1.1
    0000000000000000 l    d  .rodata.str1.8 0000000000000000 .rodata.str1.8
    0000000000000000 l    d  .text.unlikely 0000000000000000 .text.unlikely
    0000000000000000 l     F .text.unlikely 000000000000012e _tr_util_write_v4_trace$constprop$126
    0000000000000620 l     O .rodata        0000000000000017 __ZZ22tr_util_write_v4_traceE12__FUNCTION__
    0000000000000710 l     O .rodata        000000000000000d __ZZN13BFD_ALLOCATORnwEmE12__FUNCTION__
    0000000000000000 l    d  .gcc_except_table      0000000000000000 .gcc_except_table
    0000000000000700 l     O .rodata        0000000000000010 __ZZN13BFD_ALLOCATORdlEPvmE12__FUNCTION__
    00000000000006f0 l     O .rodata        0000000000000010 __ZZN13BFD_ALLOCATORdlEPvE12__FUNCTION__
    00000000000006d0 l     O .rodata        0000000000000013 __ZZN13BFD_ALLOCATORdaEPvE12__FUNCTION__
    00000000000006c0 l     O .rodata        0000000000000010 __ZZN13BFD_ALLOCATORdlEPvRKSt9nothrow_tE12__FUNCTION__
    00000000000006a0 l     O .rodata        0000000000000013 __ZZN13BFD_ALLOCATORdaEPvRKSt9nothrow_tE12__FUNCTION__
    0000000000000000 l    d
```

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to indicate that the linker found the compiled code of a `function` outside the global `Text segment`. However, this is illegal. All program instructions should be embedded inside the `Text segment`.

Could provide us more detail regarding your compilation/linking process?

Comment: The snippet from the object dump below.

Comment: From the linker script we find that .text.* i.e all section with any suffix after .text.* is placed under .text section. We find that certain functions are suffixed to .text.xxxx as unique section names.  We dont find the compiler option "-function-sections" in our compilation steps.

Comment: Objdump snippet is pasted above.